# I want to use my form inputs to set origin and destination

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

MapBox

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'place1' of undefined

this is my code and it gives me an error that 'this.state.place1' is undefined.
any idea?

I am using react js

```js
componentDidMount() {
    
    console.log(this.props)

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer, 
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mbuhaya/ck8uoff901jzv1ir0spc6gk99',
      center: [-82.907120, 40.417286],
      zoom: 6
    })

    var directions = new MapboxDirections({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      unit: 'metric',
      profile: 'mapbox/driving',
      interactive: false,
      controls: false
    })

    map.addControl(directions);

    map.on('load', function(){      
        directions.setOrigin(this.state.place1)
        directions.setDestination(this.state.place2)
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check you state. It seems like you have no defined place1

so If u using class components you can define it like

```
class YouClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {place1: "some value"};
  }
/// some code
}
```

Or this on for funciton component if you're using hooks

```
function YourComponent() {

  const [place1, setPlace1] = useState("default Value);

/// some code here 
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html - hooks 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html - state in classcomponent

Comment: i am using class components and I ready defined place1 and place2, but still not works

Comment: Show me your constructor.

Comment: problem solved, I will post my answer it was about lifecycle method.

Comment: ahh, you wanted to see route. okey

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.showRoute();
}

componentDidMount() {



  console.log(this)


       this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.mapContainer, 
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mbuhaya/ck8uoff901jzv1ir0spc6gk99',
        center: [-82.907120, 40.417286],
        zoom: 6
      })

      this.directions = new MapboxDirections({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        unit: 'metric',
        profile: 'mapbox/driving',
        interactive: false,
        controls: false,
      })

    this.map.addControl(this.directions);
    this.map.on('load', () => {
       this.showRoute()
    });

  //


  }

  showRoute(){

    const st = this.props.userData.startAddress;
    const en = this.props.userData.endAddress;
    this.directions.setOrigin(st)
    this.directions.setDestination(en)


  }
```